# The page is not redirecting after Recaptcha verification

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha, invisible-recaptcha

**Updated Que:**
I am trying to validate the invisible Google Recaptcha after form validation, If there is any suspicious activity, I know this is fixed by the Google Recaptcha API. It is giving tokens all the time (which I am validating on all side curl calls)

Issue: After submitting the form, the Recaptcha window appears and after Recaptcha verification, the page is not submitting automatically.

**Que updated with [gaetanom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3880585/gaetanom). 's solution**

**My Script:**

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=onloadCallback&render=explicit"
        async defer></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

var onloadCallback = function() {
    grecaptcha.render('g-recaptcha', {
        'sitekey' : '6Lf7X68ZAAAAAMAyjWey_BRNhGvwi4jHBLIdzYjM',
        'callback' : setResponse
      });
    };

function setResponse(response) {
    alert(response);
    document.getElementById('captcha-response').value = response;
}



jQuery(myForm).on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // avoid to submit
   if (validation() == true) {
        grecaptcha.execute();
    }else {
        this.submit();
    }
});

</script>

<div id="g-recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-size="invisible"></div>
<input type="hidden" id="captcha-response" name="captcha-response" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in this line:

```
jQuery(assessment_form).submit(function ()
```

In order to avoid to submit the form you can change the previous line to:

```
jQuery('#assessment_form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();  // avoid to submit
    if (validation() == true) {
        grecaptcha.execute();
    } else {
        this.submit();
    }
});
```

Another way is to change the input from type=submit to input type=button.

Comment: there is another issue now once i have applied your solution, que updated with new content.

Comment: actually my form is too large, i cant make a sample with is.. do you have another way to solve it , please

Comment: "que updated with new content. " = means question updated with more new details.

Comment: Should we move to chat ?

Comment: in StackOverflow chat rooms

Comment: "can you remove this.submit();?"  tried but still page not submitting, even google Recaptcha working fine, but after verification is done, page not submitting

Comment: The issue has been resolved with another way. Thanks for your help.